# JodaTime very slow on first call

Tags: java, performance, static, jodatime

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long time=System.currentTimeMillis();
        new LocalDate(2000,1, 1);
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-time);
        time=System.currentTimeMillis();
        new LocalDate(2000,1, 1);
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-time);
    }
}
```

The first call to new LocalDate takes 110ms.
The second call takes 0ms.

Firstly how do I run all the static initializers for a given class?
Secondly, is there a way to do this for all classes my application references in advance?

My application is very latency sensitive.

Comment: If the application is latency sensitive you might want to warm up the code as well as load it. e.g. run it 10,000 times or so to ensure the code is compiled. Also I would use System.nanoTime() for better resolution. You would do this on startup before your service is available.

Comment: How do I run the code in advance..e.g. if the code is writing to a DB?

Comment: Is there a way to get a list of all classes which are being referenced/imported?

Comment: I wouldn't use a database in the most latency critical part of your application if you can. If you have to, you can write nothing to a database many times. e.g. update nothing. In the case of JodaTime, you can just create 10,000 LocalDate objects, but you are better off identifying the entire critcal path of your application and warming it all up if you can.

Comment: Getting the list is not easy, nor will it help you much as the JIT compiles code based on how it is used. You can't just warmup a list of classes.

Comment: The issue I'm trying to fix here is more the static initializers running first time the class is loaded rather than the JIT optimizations.

Comment: I think you should use both ways to get maximum effect. I'd suggest to consider a warm-up stage for your components where you will be pre-loading classes and doing dynamic initialization respectively to particular case. I've checked and have improvements of 47ms instead of 63ms using 'Class.forName("org.joda.time.LocalDate")' and zero latency when used this with 'ISOChronology.getInstanceUTC()'. That means each case needs to be investigated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of classes loaded with `-XX:+TraceClassLoading` and save this to a file.
You can then use Class.forName() to ensure all these classes have loaded.

This will load every class and ensure their static blocks have been loaded.

However for latency sentive code, you really need to ensure it has been compiled by warming it up (i.e. calling it enough times to trigger compilation) This can reduce latency by a further factor of 10 or more.

---

If you run

```
public class CallStatic {
    public static void main(String... args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("Static");
    }
}

class Static {
    static {
        System.out.println("static block run");
    }
}
```

prints

```
static block run
```

Trying to create an instance won't load the class more. It may load the default constructor if it has one, but that will only help if thats the one you want.

Comment: Class.forName().class.newInstance() has more performance improvements.

Answer (score 2):

This is just how Java and the JVM works - it always needs a warm-up before running optimally. You should make some integration tests that exercise all the parts of your application, preferably in a way that's non-destructive to data. Then run them against the application each time you deploy it. This will have a bonus of reassuring you that the application is working.

Comment: I dont see how integration tests will affect the performance of the production code? They are run before deployment in a separate environment/VM.

Comment: You'd run them again (carefully!!) against the production version. (Only do that if they're non-destructive)

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea! Surely it would be better just to run initialization code and keep testing procedures out of production.

Comment: You'd just be re-purposing the tests. Of course it depends how well written they are. Up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like static initialization issue. Try do

```
Class.forName("org.joda.time.LocalDate");
```

before your calls. This should decrease timing. Probably you will need to force other related classes to be loaded. This will not help if the issue is dynamic initialization.

Comment: Is that any better or more readable than `new LocalDate(); // ensure class initialized` ?

Comment: How can you do this without Strings so refactoring works better?

Comment: @DD Class.forName(LocalDate.class.getName());

Comment: This doesn't work very well as I need to load lots of other classes...this seems to work better LocalDate.class.newInstance();